# Cannot get file name when upload file in google app script

Tags: file-upload, google-apps-script

I want to get file name when upload file finish. I have this [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/file-upload) and follow this code.

However, when I get file name from following code:

```
var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
```

The result is always return string "FileUpload".

How can I get the file name? Thank you so much.

Comment: Doc.getName() gives "FileUpload"?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new for google app script. Could you please suggest or explain what do you mean for Doc.getName()? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example script you were following produces a DocsList [`File`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file) object. This object has a method [`getName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#getName%28%29) so to extend the function in the example…

```
function doPost(e) {
  // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);

  var fileName = doc.getName();

}
```

give that a whirl.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name of the file by using  the following code.

```
var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
fileBlob.getName();
```

You can get the name of the file without storing in Drive through this.

Since fileBlob is of type blob we are getting through e.parameter.name, we have to refer Class Blob for that.

For further methods supported by Class Blob refer to
[Class Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob).