# Google form file uploads: getting filenames

Tags: google-apps-script, file-upload, google-drive-api, google-forms

Other users posted similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58427528/google-form-file-upload-get-filename-instead-of-link-to-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149540/cannot-get-file-name-when-upload-file-in-google-app-script). I tried to replicate the answer but received it as undefined. My users are permitted to upload up to 5 files, I would like to append the filenames as responses in (up to) 5 columns in a spreadsheet.

I presume that I would be able to get the filenames once I have the URLs using the following example.

```
function driveFile(){
//e.values[1] is apparently the file URL 
var url = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bVbNAnES33oY4gx8npdp51ZSMekQalk"
var id = url.split("=")[1];
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
var fileName = file.getName();
}
```

I tried this as suggested in the other question and it returned undefined.
I also tried using 0 as it made sense to get the URLs of the different files as 0 to 4.

```
 var file = e.values[1]
```

I also tried the example from the other question but to no avail. I'm also not sure if it would return the URLs concatenated or in an array.

```
var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
```

I would appreciate any guidance in this topic. Get URL → Filenames for (up to) 5 files submitted via Google Forms.

Comment: When and how are you running `driveFile()`? To get the context of the form submission you need to run the function on a trigger and your function doesn't have the event parameter either. I tested your first function with a valid file URL in my Drive and it ran perfectly as expected.

Comment: Dear Rafa, I'm not running driveFile(). I'm trying to retrieve the file URL first, sorry for the confusing layout of my question.

Comment: How are you getting the URLs? I ran `var url = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=<example-file-id>'; var id = url.split('=')[1]; Logger.log(DriveApp.getFileById(id).getName());` and was able to log the name of the file with no problem. Are you trying to get the filename on form submission?

Comment: Dear Rafa, Yes, I am trying to get the URLs of all files that were uploaded during the submission.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*This can be done using an `onSubmit()` trigger attached to the Google Form.*

#### Further information:

The problem you are encountering is that `values` is not a parameter of the event object obtained on form submission - this is why you are getting an undefined return.

Form responses are a *little* more complicated than this - they are objects with predefined methods and in order to obtain the information out of them you need to use the methods provided in the Apps Script Documentation for Forms.

#### Code:

```js
function onSubmit(e) {
  // Assumiung the question which asks for the file upload is question 1
  // Change this to the correct question number:
  var uploadQuestionNumber = 1;

  var formResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var names = [];
  var fileUploads = formResponses[uploadQuestionNumber - 1];
  for (i = 0; i < fileuploads.getResponse().length; i++) {
    name.push(DriveApp.getFileById(fileUploads.getResponse()[i]));
  }

  return name;
}
```

Variable `name` will return an array of all the file names of the uploaded files. You can then use this to put into a Sheet using `SpreadsheetApp`.

#### References:

- [Google Forms events - Form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1)
- [Class `FormResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)
- [Class `ItemResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response.html)
- [Class `DriveApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)

  - [`getFileById(id)` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String))
  - [Class `File`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file.html)